# Select only columns that have at most N unique values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I want to count the number of unique values in each column and select only those columns which have less than 32 unique values.

I tried using 
`df.filter(nunique<32)`
 and

```
df[[ c for df.columns in df if c in c.nunique<32]]
```

but because nunique is a method and not function they don't work. Thought len(set() would work and tried

```
df.apply(lambda x : len(set(x))
```

but doesn't work as well. Any ideas please? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`nunique` can be called on the entire DataFrame (you have to call it). You can then filter out columns using `loc`:

```
df.loc[:, df.nunique() < 32]
```

---

**Minimal Verifiable Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('abbcde'), 'B': list('ababab')})
df
   A  B
0  a  a
1  b  b
2  b  a
3  c  b
4  d  a
5  e  b

df.nunique()
A    5
B    2
dtype: int64

df.loc[:, df.nunique() < 3]
   B
0  a
1  b
2  a
3  b
4  a
5  b
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone wants to do it in a method chaining fashion, you can:

```py
df.loc[:, lambda x: x.nunique() < 3]
```